# Force a TestCafé to abort the execution of a test if it get stuck

Tags: testing, automation, electron, testcafe

I am working with TestCafé 1.8.1 and testcafe-browser-provider-electron 0.0.14. Let's say that an issue in the application force it to get stuck and hang one test execution, and for that reason, the rest of the test in my suite cannot continue executing. Is there a way to force TestCafé to abort the execution of that test after a timeout and continue running the rest of the test in the suite?

I have faced this issue several times and it's a problem because I am not able to see the results of the rest of the "good" tests, just because of one test that hanged the whole execution.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe reloads a browser and restarts the latest test if the application got stuck. Currently TestCafe cannot drop this test in such a case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dmitry. I have found an odd case where the execution has the behavior your mention when I'm debugging, but not when I trigger a normal execution. Looking at the Electron's console, I can see that hammerhead starts looping in some kind of no-resolved promise and for that reason, it hangs and it never restarts.

Comment: Can you provide a video to show how you reproduce the problem? Make sure that the callstack with the problem is visible